# Trying to change c++ code that was started in linux mint to windows with eclipse, getting stack error

Tags: c++

I've began making a program in linux with c++ and I'm trying to make it work on windows.  It compiles fine, but when run I get this error: "1 [main] Trails of Cold Steel Simulator 8748 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to Trails of Cold Steel Simulator.exe.stackdump". In the stack trace this exception occurs: "Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION". Here's some code;

```
#include "Tachi.h"
#include "AutumnLeafCutter.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Weapon.h"
#include "Armour.h"
#include "Shoes.h"

int main() {

    int stats[12] = {15,110,10,4,2,1,2,4,4,3,7,1};

    Tachi* Tachi1 = new Tachi(stats, "Tachi");

    Tachi1->addEquipment(new PracticeSword());
    Tachi1->addEquipment(new LeatherJacket());
    Tachi1->addEquipment(new WorkBoots());

    Tachi1->addMasterQuartz(new Forcelvl1());

    std::string input;

    std::cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";


    while(input != "q") {


        std::cout << "Your current stats are:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\n";

        std::cout << "HP   EP   STR   DEF   ATS   ADF   SPD   DEX   AGL   MOV   RNG" << std::endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i += 1) {
            std::cout << Tachi1->getBaseStats()[i] << "   ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n";


        std::cout << "Select a Craft by typing its name:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < Tachi1->getCrafts().size(); i++) {
            std::cout << Tachi1->getCrafts()[i]->getName() << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;

        getline(std::cin, input);

        if(Tachi1->findCraft(input) != NULL) {
            Tachi1->useCraft(input);
        } else {
            std::cout << "You do not have this craft." << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "\n\n\n";

    }
}
```

Im extremely sorry for any formatting, I've never posted here. The error comes from lines 14,15,16 and 18. When I replaced all the "new xxx()" with NULL and comment out the body of the function with them, the program works. It does this for both addEquipment() and addMasterQuartz(). This is the functions;

```
void Character::addEquipment(Equipment* e) {
    equipment.push_back(e);
    std::cin.get();
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        baseStats[i] += equipment[equipment.size()]->getStatsModifier()[i];
    }
}
```

and

```
void Character::addMasterQuartz(MasterQuartz* mq) {
    masterQuartz = mq;

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        baseStats[i] += masterQuartz->getStatsModifier()[i];
    }
}
```

Im guessing its a problem with the baseStats[i] += xxx stuff as its the only thing that occurs in both, but I have no idea how to fix that. It could also occur when the stuff is made using new xxx().
I can provide whatever else is needed. Thanks!!!!

EDIT:
I kept testing and the problem seems to lie in the creating of the objects. It worked on linux. Here is one of the object codes, they are all similiar and all crash the program;

```
#include "Armour.h"

Armour::Armour(int* sm, std::string n):Equipment(sm, n) {}

LeatherJacket::LeatherJacket():Armour(stats, armourName) {}
```

with header file;

```
#ifndef ARMOUR_H
#define ARMOUR_H
#include "Equipment.h"


class Armour:public Equipment {
public:
    Armour(int* sm, std::string n);
};



class LeatherJacket:public Armour {
    int stats[12] = {0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    std::string armourName = "Leather Jacket";

public: 
    LeatherJacket();
};

#endif
```

As soon as I remembered I did this I tried compiling (I think) with -std=c++11, it didnt help.

Comment: `equipment[equipment.size()]` looks suspicious to me.

Comment: LeatherJacket's constructor passes its members to the Armour base-class constructor before they exist! You can learn how constructors behave [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order)

Comment: 500 - Internal Server Error, thats a good find, but I changed it to see if it was the problem and forgot to change it back. Thanks for the heads up though :).

Comment: @Useless Thanks for the comment. I may just be tired, but I'm unsure of how to change the code to fix such a problem. Thanks.

Comment: To me it looks like `Armour` should have stats and a name, initialized from the arguments passed to its constructor (which you currently ignore). `LeatherArmour` doesn't need an additional copy per instance, it just needs one of each for the whole class - so they should be `const static` members. This means their lifetime begins before you try passing them into the base-class constructor, and you'll be able to access both members in every type of Armour in the future, from a reference to the base Armour class.

Comment: @Useless Im really sorry, this is still going over my head. I appreciate your help, I just don't quite understand what to change to fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. I could write an answer showing what that code should look like, but I don't know if it'll fix your problem - it's just one bug I happened to notice. Do you know how to move those two members to `Armour`? Do you know how to use the arguments you already pass to `Armour::Armour` but currently ignore? Do you know what a [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) data member is?

Comment: @Useless buddy if I knew how to do the things you were asking, I would have done them :/. Like I said, I've only ever coded on linux, I've never encountered a bug like this. An example is always good, especially when I can't follow just by reading. Sorry for not understanding I guess.

Comment: Answered in detail. This stuff isn't Linux-vs-anything else, it's just basic language knowledge - take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your error

```
baseStats[i] += equipment[equipment.size()]->getStatsModifier()[i];
```

By definition this is an out of bounds access on your vector, if a vector has a certain size, then the valid indexes are 0 to size - 1, not 0 to size.

It's fairly obvious that you wanted to access the last item in the vector. You can do that like this

```
baseStats[i] += equipment[equipment.size() - 1]->getStatsModifier()[i];
```

but even clearer is to use the `back` method.

```
baseStats[i] += equipment.back()->getStatsModifier()[i];
```

Another way would be to use the `e` variable you've just pushed onto the vector.

```
baseStats[i] += e->getStatsModifier()[i];
```

Adding some detail to the problem spotted by Useless, this code is incorrect.

```
class LeatherJacket : public Armour {
    int stats[12] = {0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    std::string armourName = "Leather Jacket";

public: 
    LeatherJacket();
};

LeatherJacket::LeatherJacket() : Armour(stats, armourName) {}
```

The problem is the order in which things happen. First the `Armour` constructor is called, then the `stats` and `armourName` variables are initialised. So the call to the `Armour` constructor is using uninitiialised variables and will likely crash.

Several solutions possible, the best is probably to use virtual functions.

Making a couple of assumptions about `Equipment` (which isn't specified the question) it seems you should do something like this.

```
// header file
class Equipment
{
public:
    virtual ~Equipment() {}
    virtual std::string getName() const = 0;
    virtual const int* getStatsModifier() const = 0;
};

class Armour : public Equipment
{
};

class LeatherJacket : public Armour
{
    static const int stats[12];
public:
    virtual std::string getName() const { return "Leather Jacket"; }
    virtual const int* getStatsModifier() const { return stats; }
};

// source file
const int LeatherJacket::stats[12] = {0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

This answer adds pure virtual functions to the base class `Equipment` (which has become an interface), and implements those functions in `LeatherJacket`. Because the functions are virtual the appropriate function will always be called and there no need to pass the information down to `Equipment`. Also since it seems to be per-class constant data, `stats` has been made `static const`. Until you get to C++17 static const arrays must be defined in a source file, not the header file, as shown above.

Comment: I really appreciate the comment, but this hasn't fixed it. I believe Useless has described whats wrong above but I'm not good enough at c++ to understand what he means.

Comment: Are you refering to his first or second comment? And is the code in the question now the code you actually have i.e. it's not still before you forgot to change it back.

Comment: I thought they both referred to the same thing, that I call Armour and Armour calls equipment before either exist. 

I have changed the code to use e as you stated, it looks much nicer and makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Yes you're right. I'll update my answer with some more detail. But note that the bug I found is a real bug, you'll probably encounter that next.

Comment: Yep you were right, that fixed it. Thank you so much! To cement my knowledge, the reason my version didn't work is because I was trying to call stats and armourName before they were initialized, and thats because class initialization means that Armour() and Equipment() is run before the code for stats and armourName is run. It was fixed by changing the variables to static const's, meaning they were initialized immediately as the program knew they were constant.

Thank you very much!

Comment: That sounds about right. You should look into virtual functions however, they're tailor made for the type of program you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm going to replace the `int[12]` arrays with a proper type. Partly so the magic number `12` isn't littered all over the code and hard to change later, and partly because it will behave better (ie, not decay to a pointer in some contexts). This needs C++11.

```
#include <array>

using Stats = std::array<int, 12>;
```

> To me it looks like Armour should have stats and a name, initialized from the arguments passed to its constructor (which you currently ignore).

Like so:

```
class Armour: public Equipment {
public:
    Stats m_stats;
    std::string m_name;

    Armour(Stats const& s, std::string const &n) : m_stats(s), m_name(n) {}
};
```

You were already passing those two arguments to the constructor - you just weren't doing anything with them. Now you are.

This means that when we later have leather, scale, chain and plate subclasses, I can have a pointer of type `Armour*` and not need to worry about which subclass I'm looking at: the stats are available right there in the base class.

I made the members public, which is generally bad style, to save space. It might not matter for your use. I named the members with the `m_` prefix so they can't accidentally get confused with similarly-named non-members. It's broadly good style but not essential.

> `LeatherArmour` doesn't need an additional copy per instance, it just needs one of each for the whole class - so they should be const static members.

```
class LeatherJacket: public Armour {
    static const Stats stats {0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    static const std::string name{"Leather Jacket"};

public:
    LeatherJacket() : Armour(stats, name) {}
};
```

I made the `LeatherJacket`-specific stat values `static const` by writing `static const` in front of them.

The [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) means that every `LeatherJacket` has the same base stats, so you don't need a copy per instance, just one copy for the whole class. It's `const` because the base stats for leather jackets never change over time. You still have the base class member `Armour::m_stats` which *can* change as your individual leather jacket gets damaged, repaired, buffed or whatever.

Again, the `LeatherJacket` constructor was already passing (the equivalent of) these members to the base class constructor, but now they already exist (see the link above about *static storage duration*). The original instance variables *didn't* exist when you used them, because the derived (`LeatherJacket`) object and its data members aren't really constructed until *after* the base class subobject.